# ssh Connection reset by 192.168.x.x

Tags: centos, ssh, docker

I'm trying to ssh login from Mac OSX 10.10 into CentOS 7.1 on boot2docker by using public key authentication.
The problem is that ssh shows `Connection reset by 192.168.99.100` when I login to CentOs (192.168.99.100 is the container's IP address).
Here is my Dockerfile for building CentOS image:

```
FROM centos:centos7
MAINTAINER moutend <moutend@gmail.com>

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN sed -i 's/^#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/^PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
ADD id_ecdsa.pub /home/moutend/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN adduser -g wheel moutend
RUN echo moutend:foobarfoobar | chpasswd
RUN chown -R moutend:wheel /home/moutend
RUN chmod 600 /home/moutend/.ssh/authorized_keys

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

The following commands are I did.

```
# On Mac OSX
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
docker-machine scp myDockerfile id_ecdsa.pub dev:
docker-machine ssh dev # Login to boot2docker

# On boot2docker
docker build -t test -f myDockerfile .
docker run -d -P test
docker port `docker ps -lq` # Get the port for ssh
```

And then I got the error message below:

```
ssh-add id_ecdsa
ssh moutend@`docker-machine ip dev` -p 32772
Connection reset by 192.168.99.100
```

Ofcourse the port number is correct.
So I don't know why connection reset happens. How can I solve this?

Comment: make sure that also `~/.ssh` directory has proper permissions. Running the server in debug mode (`-ddd`) might also give some clue.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks. However `~/.ssh` directory is mode 700. It's proper permission.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is increase the verbosity of `ssh` by adding `-v`:

```
ssh -v moutend@`docker-machine ip dev` -p 32772
```

that will give you extra debugging information.

If that doesn't help, and assuming you used `docker run --name sshtest -d -P test` to name the container `sshtest`;

```
docker logs sshtest
```

to see if `sshd` is (still) running. (*This will show that the* `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key` *host ssh keys are missing, and you have to run* `ssh-keygen -A` *once to generate those host keys in* `/etc/ssh/`)

If it were still running you can check the setup
of the inside for correctness by `exec`-ing into the the container:

```
docker exec -it sshtest /bin/bash
```

Of course using `docker exec` eliminates the need for running `sshd` in a lot of containers in the first place.

You can also look at what others have done in similar setups (if you haven't already e.g. [this setup](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/http://)

Comment: `docker logs` shows `Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`. So I put `RUN ssh-keygen -A` into my Dockerfile, everything works fine and I can login to the container by using public key authentication. Thank you for giving me many advices!

Comment: @moutend I updated my answer with that info (so future visitors don't have to read all the way down to the comments). Consider accepting my answer (clicking the V next to it) if it solves your problem, that is the way people seeing your question on this site, know it has a working answer.